# Why can I only texture paint some parts of the model

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I am only able to paint some parts of the model but it just doesn't add any color to some other parts or the color it got added is very faint. Please see the red circled area in the screenshot. I am really confused about this. Can someone please let me know what I did wrong here? Thanks.

[image: screenshot]

I also checked the UV unwrapping and all the normals associated to that area which seem okay.

[image: normals]

Comment: Your Uv seems to be squished at those points, you might need to UV unwrap this

Comment: Yep, the UV unwrap is done. And the normals of those areas seem good. It seems that the colors painted in one stroke are in different shade, and some parts are missing.

Comment: I notice that in the first image the little bit of the uv that shows up with what you selected seems to be squished into a single axis, perhaps placing some seams and then smart unwrapping will help:?

Comment: Ah okay...I tried smart unwrapping and now the painting is much smooth and in uniform color. Thanks a lot! I think I used "project from view" for unwrapping previously. Curious why it didn't work that way :-)  So when I was painting on the model previously, the face was actually not selected for the painting because of the squished parts caused by the unwrap method?

Comment: Well it was technically allowing texture painting but it was having some strange effects due to the weird UV map.

Comment: Okay. Anyway thanks for the help! I was wondering how I can accept your comment as answer. Maybe only after you posted this as an answer :-)

Comment: Yeah I'll make it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first photo the reason why your texture looks so strange is because the UV associated with that face is squished in a way that it can only take the colour of a single row of pixels. A way to fix this is to select some of your edges and right click, then create seams. Then select everything and press U, then smart unwrap. This should be able to make your UV map easier to work with.

Comment: It worked! Thank you!

Comment: No problem, have a good day